# Change of context path of stopped applications on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat8

Im working on a Tomcat application. I just updated from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 using the migration guide.
After I did this, I recognized that the context path of the applications deployed on the server behaves different now.

I am requesting the context path in a jsp. deployed in the ROOT directory using:

```
application.getContext("app").getContextPath()
```

The result is the context path of the application: */app*

The context path is always the same, if the application is running or stopped.

After upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.33 the behavior is different.
When the application is stopped, the context path that I get is an empty path (which results in pointing to ROOT).
The context path of the runnnig application is still the same: */app*

I studied the migration guide and change log but I did not find any change which explains the different behavior.
I also googles a lot and have no clue what explains this behavior.

Can anybody help me finding out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think I did not clear enough explain what I am doing. I do not want the current context path of the application.

On the Tomcat are various numbers of applications deployed (let the names be /app1, /app2, ..., /app10). Inside the jsp, deployed in ROOT, I want the to find out which applications are actually deployed on the server. I am doing this by asking for the ServletContext of the other applications:

```
application.getContext( "/app1);
application.getContext( "/app2);
...
```

When I then asking for the context path of the application it is either empty (application is not deployed) or I get the actual path (e.g. /app1) for a deployed application (started or stopped):

```
application.getContext("/appX").getContextPath()
```

Thats how I create a list of deployed applications.
But now on Tomcat 8 I get an empty context path not only for applications which are not deployed, but also for applications which are deployed but stopped. This is a different behavior as it was on Tomcat 7.

I hope I could make clearer now what´s my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not find out what´s the issue. Instead I rewrote my code to use the tomcat manager endpoints.